# Draw a shape when an input changes

Tags: events, electron, paperjs

I am having a blast learning electron/node.js. I am trying to use paper.js to "encode" a string into an image, sort of...

I am using a "paperscript" file like this:

```
<script type="text/paperscript" src="mainCanvas.js" canvas="mainCanvas">
```

Basically, I am looking at how I can wire up events from say, an input to the paper context.

What I would like is or whenever the target input changes (`$("#input").on("change"...)`) for something (the something is not the issue here) to happen.

I wiring up the event directly in the paperscript file:

```
$("#mainInput").on("change", function() {
    path.moveTo(50, 25);
})
```

But that did not work. Reading the documentation, it seems the context *should* have access to any global objects.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: don't u have error reported regarding jquery?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly where your problem is, but here is a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/3wkLsxe8/) demonstrating how it can be done.

```
// draw square
var square = new Path.RegularPolygon({
    center     : view.center,
    radius     : 50,
    sides      : 4,
    fillColor  : 'orange',
    applyMatrix: false
});

// on input change
$('#input').change(function ()
{
    // rotate it accordingly to input value
    square.rotation = this.value;
});
```